# JQuery: How to do validation on blur of a text box?

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox with ID "name", I want to do validation when the text box get onblur function. The below code doesn't work. What's wrong with me?

```
  $(function() {
    $('name').validate({
      rules:{ "name": {required: true, minlength: 5 } }
    });
    $('name').blur(function(){
      $('name').validate()
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/qC2Ya/ **or this one is way more shorter and cooler** http://jsfiddle.net/XdAkv/

All you need to do is add an element validation on `blur` event and that will work like a rocket.

See validation element api : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element

Hope this helps `:)`

**code**

```
var v = $("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function() {
        console.log('successful submit');
        return false;
    }
});

$('#firstName').blur(function(){
   v.element('#firstName');
});

$('#lastName').blur(function(){
   v.element('#lastName');
});
```

**OR** from second demo

```
$("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function() {
        console.log('successful submit');
        return false;
    }
});

$('#firstName,#lastName').blur(function(){
    $("form").validate().element($(this))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `onfocusout` option, set to `false` will validate elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur. The [doc](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

```
$('form').validate({
  onfocusout: false,
  rules:{ "name": {required: true, minlength: 5 } }
});
```

Comment: Indeed, this is valid as well +1. `:)`

Comment: I don't have the form element...it is just a text box

Comment: thanks for your comment, can you provide an example of this configuration on jsfiddle. I really can't get this work